# THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor, can't figure what to do

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

I'm trying to add OrbitControls, but I always get this error at this instruction:

`var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );`

I've installed with npm three.js and three-orbitcontrols.js, I've read all the answers but I still can't figure out what I should do. If I use `require` or `import` in my jsp page, I still get this problem.
I've also tryied using browserify but it didn't help (I got an EPERM error, so maybe I did something wrong?).

Can someone help me? What did I miss?

**Edit:** I've realized that I wrote OrbitControls.js instead of three-orbitcontrols.js, so sorry about that. Also, if I try to use import console says:" SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: It looks like OrbitControls is a separate dependency or import (and not a method of THREE). https://threejs.org/docs/examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was that I used browserify in the wrong folder: now I've created the bundles and it works, thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `three-orbitcontrols` since `OrbitControls` isn't in the `three.js` npm package.

To install `OrbitControls` use

```
npm install three-orbitcontrols
```

**Edit**

The `OrbitControls` npm package said:

> three-js exposes real modules now via three/examples/jsm/... for example to import Orbit, do import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'

So, you can use real modules using

```
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import like this

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

at the top of the file.